# Updating the App Widget from the configuration Activity and getting the result value

Tags: android

In my Weather App Widget, i'm  updating Widget from the configuration activity using the place name entered by the user for the first time.After updating the widget, i'm creating a return intent and finishing the activity. I'm giving the code below.

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
```

But how i'll get the return value(placename) in the AppWidgetprovider class,so that i can update the widget automatically at a later time.
Thanks in Advance.